# Can't Migrate Mongodb from version 3.4 to 3.6 using Meteor 1.2.0.2

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

We need to migrate our current Mongodb 3.4 to version 3.6 but the recommendations don't work.
Mongo says that you need to send the cursor option in aggregates, which I am doing like: someCollection.aggregate(pipeline, {cursor: {}}).
Our aggregates work well using mongodb 3.4, but when trying to run them in 3.6, they don't work.
The app is written with Meteor framework, version 1.2.0.2

The packages related to Mongodb are:

1. dburles:mongo-collection-instances@0.3.4
2. minimongo@1.0.10
3. mongo@1.1.2
4. mongo-id@1.0.1
5. mongo-livedata@1.0.9
6. npm-mongo@1.4.39_1

The pipeline for this example is:

```
let pipeline = [
  {$match: {'contractor._id': contractorId, _id: {$ne: apptId}, start: {$lte: appt.start}}},
  {$unwind: '$notes'},
  {$sort: {start: -1, 'notes.creationDate': 1}}
];
```

Following are the options I've tried

#1:

```
    var result = SalesAppointment.aggregate(pipeline, {cursor: {}});
    return result;
```

#2:

```
    var result = SalesAppointment.aggregate(pipeline, {cursor: {}});
    return result.toArray();
```

#3:

```
    var result = SalesAppointment.aggregate(pipeline, {cursor: {}});
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve(result.toArray());
    });
```

#4:

```
    var result = SalesAppointment.aggregate(pipeline, {cursor: {}});
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve(result);
    });
```

#5:

```
    let rawCol = SalesAppointment.rawCollection();
    let aggregateQuery = Meteor.wrapAsync(rawCol.aggregate, rawCol);
    return aggregateQuery(pipeline, {cursor: {}});
```

#6:

```
    var result = SalesAppointment.rawCollection().aggregate(pipeline, {cursor: {}});
    return result;
```

// RESULT #1 to #5: All the options make the app to hang, it never gets to the return statement, and client never gets the promise resolved.

// RESULT #6: It returns an object with no data to the frontend, it only has these properties: _readableState, readable, domain, _events, _maxListeners.
In the backend it has these methods: explain, get, getOne, each, next, close, _read.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should probably migrate from Meteor 1.2 as well :) Perhaps not an easy task

Comment: Thank you, migrating Meteor is something we have to do but it can't be done right now, the app is pretty big so it would take a long time, the owner needs an easier and faster solution.

Comment: That sounds familiar, no maintenance for several years, then looking for a quick fix. I'd be looking to set up a mongo server running 3.4 - probably the easiest solution of all

Comment: That's the case basically xD. And yeah that's our next option, but first we want to try to make it work through a change in the Meteor code.